# Undo delete line android studio

Tags: android-studio

In android studio, CTRL+Y key delete all my lines of code. But revert back with CTRL+Z  does not work. I lost atleast 300 lines of code. Is there a shortcut key to get back the code.

Comment: unless you already saved it, you can close it and say no when the confirmation: "do you want to save changes" comes out.

Comment: The exit confirmation dialog won't display, android studio will close automatically